# Why fails Travis CI to retrieve a SNAPSHOT artifact when retrieval works locally?

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I'm suffering for a [`Could not find artifact org.apache.commons:commons-numbers-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT` Maven error](https://travis-ci.org/document-scanner/document-scanner-aggregator/builds/254183128#L7638) on Travis CI which I can't explain because I ran the exact same build command locally after deleting `~/.m2/repository` and moving `~/.m2/settings.xml` to a backup location.

The error message is

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-maven-plugin:5.1.1:izpack (default) on project document-scanner: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-maven-plugin:5.1.1:izpack failed: 
Plugin org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-maven-plugin:5.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
org.apache.commons:commons-numbers-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,
org.apache.commons:commons-numbers-gamma:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,
org.apache.commons:commons-numbers-fraction:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,
org.apache.commons:commons-numbers-combinatorics:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,
org.apache.commons:commons-numbers-arrays:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,
org.apache.commons:commons-numbers-angle:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,
org.apache.commons:commons-rng-sampling:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT:
Could not find artifact org.apache.commons:commons-numbers-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT`
```

which makes me think that the SNAPSHOT version is required by `izpack-maven-plugin` so that I can't avoid it.

Afaik the repositories ought to be picked up based on `repository` elements in `pom.xml`s which are equal on the local and Travis CI's side. The issue occurs for > 12h, now and 100% of the time (restarted the Travis CI build 3 times), so that a caching issue is unlikely.

I'm using Maven 3.1.1 which is enforced by one dependency which I modified and which I'm building in an aggregator project.

Comment: Do you really need a SNAPSHOT version of an Apache project?

Comment: It seems like the SNAPSHOT version is declared as dependency of `izpack-maven-plugin`, so I can't control it afaik.

Comment: You could try to exclude it in the pom.xml, and add a non-SNAPSHOT version as a dependency yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache-snapshots-group</id>
        <name>Apache snapshots group repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
        <!-- fix missing `commons-numbers-core:1.0-SNAPSHOT` on Travis CI
        -->
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>apache-snapshots-group</id>
        <name>Apache snapshots group repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
        <!-- fix missing `commons-numbers-core:1.0-SNAPSHOT` on Travis CI
        -->
</pluginRepositories>
```

to the POM fixes the issue on Travis CI, although that doesn't explain why it's not necessary when building with a reset system locally (see [How to avoid issues with Maven builds on Travis CI which don't occur locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359149/how-to-avoid-issues-with-maven-builds-on-travis-ci-which-dont-occur-locally) for an eventual explanation).